# Java: Generic Array Creation

Tags: java

I'm writing my custom Map, it have custom Pair array and Map uses the pair for operations.

They are generic, I don't know their's type it can be integer, string or double. So I can not use ArrayList, It's forbidden for me.

```
public class FMap<K, V> {
   private FPair<K, V>[] data;
   int capacity=23;
   int used=0;

   public FMap(int cap){
      super();
      capacity=cap;
      used =0;
      data = new FPair[ capacity];
      for(int i=0; i< data.length; ++i)
          data[i] = new FPair<K, V>();
}
```

But compiler saying:

```
javac -g -Xlint BigramDyn.java
./TemplateLib/FMap.java:23: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: FPair
        data = new FPair[capacity];
                   ^
  missing type arguments for generic class FPair<A,B>
  where A,B are type-variables:
    A extends Object declared in class FPair
    B extends Object declared in class FPair
./TemplateLib/FMap.java:23: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
        data = new FPair[capacity];
               ^
  required: FPair<K,V>[]
  found:    FPair[]
  where K,V are type-variables:
    K extends Object declared in class FMap
    V extends Object declared in class FMap
2 warnings
```

if I use `data = new FPair<K, V>[capacity]` instead of `data = new FPair[capacity]`

Compiler is saying :

```
TemplateLib/FMap.java:23: error: generic array creation
        data = new FPair<K,V>[capacity];
               ^
1 error
```

--

And in equal function of map:
I'm doing:
FMap

```
FMap<K,V> otherPair = (FMap<K,V>) other;
```

But compiler saying:

```
./TemplateLib/FMap.java:34: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
            FMap<A,B> otherPair = (FMap<A,B>) other;
                                                ^
  required: FMap<A,B>
  found:    Object
  where A,B are type-variables:
    A extends Object declared in class FMap
    B extends Object declared in class FMap
1 warning
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compilation error: Generic array creation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863792/compilation-error-generic-array-creation)

Answer (score 0):

Use an ArrayList as such:

```
List<FPair<K, V>> data = new ArrayList<>(capacity);
```

As ArrayList wraps an array you have all the comfort of List and the functionality of an array.

Only fill in an item when there is data, no `new FPair<K, V>();`.

---

***As ArrayList is not allowed:***

```
    data = (FPair<K, V>[]) new FPair<?, ?>[10];
```

The `<?, ?>` or `<Object, Object>` will satisfy the compiler (no longer a **raw type FPair used**). The abuse/cast is unlucky. But as types are stripped, there is no actual difference.

If you want to fill every item (not advisable):

```
    Arrays.fill(data, new FPair<K, V>());

    Arrays.setAll(data, ix -> new FPair<K,V>());
```

The first fills the *same* element at every positon, usefull when FPair is not changed but can be shared: when it is "immutable".

The second is just a fancy way to loop.

Comment: very thanks but I can not use this because it is forbidden for me. 

My code is running like I want but it gives only some warnings, That's means, my code is not right, can not I use generic array like it?

Comment: @FurkanYıldız the warning doesn't necessarily mean your code is wrong, `@SuppressWarnings` is **perfectly acceptable** in some cases (mostly with generics)