# Solution to compiler warning for generic varargs

Tags: java, generics, variadic-functions

A puzzle from this [blog](http://lt-rider.blogspot.com/2011/11/java-language-puzzle-3.html). Similar to [SO1445233](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445233/is-it-possible-to-solve-the-a-generic-array-of-t-is-created-for-a-varargs-param).

Given the following source listing, explain why the compiler is producing a warning at invocation to the list method and give a solution for removing the warning without resorting to @SuppressWarnings annotation.

```
public class JavaLanguagePuzzle3 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    list("1", 2, new BigDecimal("3.5"));
  }  
  private static <T> List<T> list(T... items) {
    return Arrays.asList(items);
  }
}
```

Warning:

```
Type safety: A generic array of Object&Serializable&Comparable<?> is created for a varargs parameter
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my thoughts.

```
public static interface Foo extends Serializable, Comparable<Object> {
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  // Problem: Unsafe: varargs has generic type
  implicitList("1", 2, BigDecimal.valueOf(3.5)); // warning: generic vararg

  // Solution 1: Constrain type of varags explicitly through generics
  explicitList1(Object.class, "1", 2, BigDecimal.valueOf(3.5));
  // However, we could still have the same error from problem
  explicitList1(Foo.class, "1", 2, BigDecimal.valueOf(3.5)); // warning: generic vararg
  // Fix: Make containing class to exact type (PECS) an array is both producer and consumer
  explicitList2(Foo.class, "1", 2, BigDecimal.valueOf(3.5)); // error: incompatible args

  // Solution 2: Override varargs by passing array
  implicitList(new Object[] { "1", 2, BigDecimal.valueOf(3.5) });
}

private static <T> List<T> explicitList1(Class<? extends T> klass, T... items) {
  return Arrays.asList(items);
}

private static <T> List<T> explicitList2(Class<T> klass, T... items) {
  return Arrays.asList(items);
}

private static <T> List<T> implicitList(T... items) {
  return Arrays.asList(items);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the body of main from
`list("1", 2, new BigDecimal("3.5"));`
to 
`JavaLanguagePuzzle3.<Object>list("1", 2, new BigDecimal("3.5"));`

Reason: the `<>` syntax specifies which version of the generic method you want. But, you need to put `.` in front of it to make the parser happy, and the class name before that for the same reason.

Source: 
http://codeidol.com/java/javagenerics/Introduction/Generic-Methods-and-Varargs/

Comment: By the way, this then gives a "heap pollution" warning in Java 7 (even just the function definition without the call does this). Is this heap pollution warning inevitable?

Answer (score 1):

I asked a question on this a while ago. 
Problem: Given the method header `<T extends List<?>> void foo(T... args)` You can store non-T values in the generated array (unsafe behavior). (See my question below for more details)

Solution: In Java 7 they added a @SafeVarargs annotation you can put on your method to suppress that warning.

[Simplified Varargs Method Invocation in Java 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857282/simplified-varargs-method-invocation-in-java-7)

Answer (score 0):

The message is because there's a mixture of types as the args to `list` and the correct binding for the type parameter `T` isn't obvious. One fix (not in the spirit of type safety) is to remove the generics:

```
private static List<Object> list(Object... items) {
    return Arrays.asList(items);
}
```

Comment: I think it's more than a simple mixture of types. String and BigDecimal implement Comparable<T>, which as we can see, use Generics. Varargs is implemented as an array. So what do we have? An array of non-reifiable objects, which is a potential risk. As other response points out, we can use @SafeVarargs, or what you propose.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is actually slightly misleading. The issue here is not that the type argument is generic, it's that it's an intersection type. Only one element type of that intersection type can be reified as the component type of the array. Thus storing objects into that array which do implement some of the other element types of the intersection type will not raise an `ArrayStoreException`:

```
public class Example {
    interface A {}
    interface B {}
    interface C {}

    static class X implements A, B {}
    static class Y implements A, B, C {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // inferred type: A&B, erased down to A resulting in a A[]
        bar(new X(), new Y());
    }

    static <T> void bar(T... ts) {
        Object[] os = ts;
        os[0] = new A() {}; // should fail, does not => warning
        os[0] = new B() {}; // fails as expected
    }
}
```